# Double 'button' SDL_Event member access?

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2

Say I have this simple event handling code and I want to get the X & Y value of a left click:

```
SDL_Event = event;   
SDL_PollEvent(&event); //get the event

switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_QUIT://if the X is pressed then end the game
        isRunning = false;
        break;
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        int x, y;
        if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
            SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
            std::cout << "Xpos is: " << x << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Ypos is: " << y << std::endl;
        }
    default:
        break;
}
```

Why do I have to call `.button` twice on `event.button.button` to be able to read the X and Y coordinate?

Comment: I do not understand your question. `event.button.button` has no call and it has nothing to do with the way you are getting `x` and `y`. You use `event.button.button` only to get the mouse button clicked. As for why `button` appears twice in there, that's just the libraries design. `event.button` represent a button event and `event.button.button` represent the button for which the event happened.

Comment: Okay I just worded the question wrong by saying I was calling event.button...I was just trying to understand why you needed .button.button instead of just one .button, the second half of your comment and the two answers below clear that up for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SDL_Event`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/10fc11bbc967/include/SDL_events.h#l557) is a big 'ole [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

```
typedef union SDL_Event
{
    Uint32 type;                    /**< Event type, shared with all events */
    SDL_CommonEvent common;         /**< Common event data */
    SDL_DisplayEvent display;       /**< Window event data */
    SDL_WindowEvent window;         /**< Window event data */
    SDL_KeyboardEvent key;          /**< Keyboard event data */
    SDL_TextEditingEvent edit;      /**< Text editing event data */
    SDL_TextInputEvent text;        /**< Text input event data */
    SDL_MouseMotionEvent motion;    /**< Mouse motion event data */
    SDL_MouseButtonEvent button;    /**< Mouse button event data */
    SDL_MouseWheelEvent wheel;      /**< Mouse wheel event data */
    SDL_JoyAxisEvent jaxis;         /**< Joystick axis event data */
    SDL_JoyBallEvent jball;         /**< Joystick ball event data */
    SDL_JoyHatEvent jhat;           /**< Joystick hat event data */
    SDL_JoyButtonEvent jbutton;     /**< Joystick button event data */
    SDL_JoyDeviceEvent jdevice;     /**< Joystick device change event data */
    SDL_ControllerAxisEvent caxis;      /**< Game Controller axis event data */
    SDL_ControllerButtonEvent cbutton;  /**< Game Controller button event data */
    SDL_ControllerDeviceEvent cdevice;  /**< Game Controller device event data */
    SDL_AudioDeviceEvent adevice;   /**< Audio device event data */
    SDL_SensorEvent sensor;         /**< Sensor event data */
    SDL_QuitEvent quit;             /**< Quit request event data */
    SDL_UserEvent user;             /**< Custom event data */
    SDL_SysWMEvent syswm;           /**< System dependent window event data */
    SDL_TouchFingerEvent tfinger;   /**< Touch finger event data */
    SDL_MultiGestureEvent mgesture; /**< Gesture event data */
    SDL_DollarGestureEvent dgesture; /**< Gesture event data */
    SDL_DropEvent drop;             /**< Drag and drop event data */

    /* This is necessary for ABI compatibility between Visual C++ and GCC
       Visual C++ will respect the push pack pragma and use 52 bytes for
       this structure, and GCC will use the alignment of the largest datatype
       within the union, which is 8 bytes.

       So... we'll add padding to force the size to be 56 bytes for both.
    */
    Uint8 padding[56];
} SDL_Event;
```

The first `button` selects the `SDL_MouseButtonEvent` member:

```
typedef struct SDL_MouseButtonEvent
{
    Uint32 type;        /**< ::SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or ::SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP */
    Uint32 timestamp;   /**< In milliseconds, populated using SDL_GetTicks() */
    Uint32 windowID;    /**< The window with mouse focus, if any */
    Uint32 which;       /**< The mouse instance id, or SDL_TOUCH_MOUSEID */
    Uint8 button;       /**< The mouse button index */
    Uint8 state;        /**< ::SDL_PRESSED or ::SDL_RELEASED */
    Uint8 clicks;       /**< 1 for single-click, 2 for double-click, etc. */
    Uint8 padding1;
    Sint32 x;           /**< X coordinate, relative to window */
    Sint32 y;           /**< Y coordinate, relative to window */
} SDL_MouseButtonEvent;
```

The second `button` is the actual mouse button index in `SDL_MouseButtonEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_Event` is [defined as a union](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlevent.html), so saying `event.button` is the way you access the event data as an `SDL_MouseButtonEvent`. Then, `SDL_MouseButtonEvent::button` gives you the actual mouse button index.

You could clarify this a bit like so:

```
SDL_Event = event;   
SDL_PollEvent(&event); //get the event

switch (event.type) {
    . . .
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        const SDL_MouseButtonEvent &mouse_event = event.button;
        int x, y;
        if (mouse_event.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
            SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
            std::cout << "Xpos is: " << x << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Ypos is: " << y << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    }
    . . .
}
```